# Which parallel patterns are useful to do this?

Tags: java

My program has a service layer, what is provide (business) datas from dao to views. Like this:

```
package service;

public class DetailsService implements IDetailsService {
    public A getA(...) { /* use dao objects */ }
    public B getB(...);
    public C getC(...) {
        // do something
        return getA() "+" getB();
    }
    public D getD(...);
}
```

In some frontend classes we are calling e.g. getA() and after getD(), in other classes we are calling getC() etc.

Now, I want to speedup the application with concurrent behaviour (e.g. getC() uses ExecutorService for execute getA() and getB() tasks). And I want that if a frontend class call getA() and after getD(), these are running concurrent or something like that.

Can I use any pattern for this? Or should I do concurrent layer above the service layer? How can I do this? Pls, give me some hints or how can I do this skillfully?

Sorry about my english... :-(

Answer (score 0):

First, since your methods return values, they need to be synchronous, so a standalone getC() call doesn't make sense on a different thread since you have to wait for it to complete and return the value. You'd need to redesign your whole service layer (and the clients calling it) to make it asynchronous - via callbacks, etc.

There are no patterns AFAIK. As far, as where it should be - definitely below the service layer. Basically move the actual implementation: getA(), getB(), getC(), etc. to some new lower level and make sure those methods are stateless or thread-safe (synchronized, etc.) Then all your server layer should do is to invoke them via a thread pool executor. Obviously if you are calling getA() and getB(), and then combining the result, you'll have to add some synchronization to wait for both. Take a look at java.util.concurrent package available since 1.5.